# Direction Vector From Quaternion

Tags: c++, camera, quaternions

I am working on making a movable camera and I use quaternions to represent the cameras rotation. I set the quaternion to default values so x = y = z = 0 and w = 1. My cameras default position is x = 0, y = 0, z = 5 where positive y is up and positive z is towards the user.

I can rotate my camera perfectly however, I cannot move it. I want the camera to move forward in the direction the camera is facing. How would I go about doing this?

I saw somewhere the following was used.

```
inline Vector3<float> GetForward() const {
    return Rotate( Vector3<float>( 0, 0, 1 ), *this );
}

Vector3<float> Rotate( const Vector3<float> &vect, const Quaternion &quat ) {
    Quaternion w = quat * vect * quat.Conjugate();
    return Vector3<float>( w.GetX(), w.GetY(), w.GetZ() );
}

inline Matrix4<float> ToRotationMatrix() {
    Matrix4<float> ret;

    ret[ 0 ][ 0 ] = GetW() * GetW() + GetX() * GetX() - GetY() * GetY() - GetZ() * GetZ();
    ret[ 0 ][ 1 ] = 2 * GetX() * GetY() - 2 * GetW() * GetZ();
    ret[ 0 ][ 2 ] = 2 * GetX() * GetZ() + 2 * GetW() * GetY();

    ret[ 1 ][ 0 ] = 2 * GetX() * GetY() + 2 * GetW() * GetZ();
    ret[ 1 ][ 1 ] = GetW() * GetW() - GetX() * GetX() + GetY() * GetY() - GetZ() * GetZ();
    ret[ 1 ][ 2 ] = 2 * GetY() * GetZ() + 2 * GetW() * GetX();

    ret[ 2 ][ 0 ] = 2 * GetX() * GetZ() - 2 * GetW() * GetY();
    ret[ 2 ][ 1 ] = 2 * GetY() * GetZ() - 2 * GetW() * GetX();
    ret[ 2 ][ 2 ] = GetW() * GetW() - GetX() * GetX() - GetY() * GetY() + GetZ() * GetZ();

    return ret;
}

inline Quaternion operator*( const Quaternion &quat ) const {
    Quaternion ret;

    ret[ 3 ] = ( *this )[ 3 ] * quat[ 3 ] - ( *this )[ 0 ] * quat[ 0 ] - ( *this )[ 1 ] * quat[ 1 ] - ( *this )[ 2 ] * quat[ 2 ];
    ret[ 0 ] = ( *this )[ 3 ] * quat[ 0 ] + ( *this )[ 0 ] * quat[ 3 ] + ( *this )[ 1 ] * quat[ 2 ] - ( *this )[ 2 ] * quat[ 1 ];
    ret[ 1 ] = ( *this )[ 3 ] * quat[ 1 ] + ( *this )[ 1 ] * quat[ 3 ] + ( *this )[ 2 ] * quat[ 0 ] - ( *this )[ 0 ] * quat[ 2 ];
    ret[ 2 ] = ( *this )[ 3 ] * quat[ 2 ] + ( *this )[ 2 ] * quat[ 3 ] + ( *this )[ 0 ] * quat[ 1 ] - ( *this )[ 1 ] * quat[ 0 ];

    return ret;
}

inline Quaternion operator*( const Vector3<float> &vect ) const {
    Quaternion ret;

    ret[ 3 ] = -( ( *this )[ 0 ] * vect[ 0 ] - ( *this )[ 1 ] * vect[ 1 ] - ( *this )[ 2 ] * vect[ 2 ] );
    ret[ 0 ] =  ( ( *this )[ 3 ] * vect[ 0 ] + ( *this )[ 1 ] * vect[ 2 ] - ( *this )[ 2 ] * vect[ 1 ] );
    ret[ 1 ] =  ( ( *this )[ 3 ] * vect[ 1 ] + ( *this )[ 2 ] * vect[ 0 ] - ( *this )[ 0 ] * vect[ 2 ] );
    ret[ 2 ] =  ( ( *this )[ 3 ] * vect[ 2 ] + ( *this )[ 0 ] * vect[ 1 ] - ( *this )[ 1 ] * vect[ 0 ] );

    return ret;
}
```

I attempted this but it just sets x, y, and z to 0 and the camera does not move. So I am unsure on how to get a directional vector from quaternions. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Turns out this method works. You just have to do your math correctly. I was multiplying by a Vector3 incorrectly. I have added the corrected code in hopes that someone else does not make the same mistake.

Comment: I think you don't have good values in your default quaternion.  Since (x, y, z) represent the axis of rotation (not a position), this may cause the movement to fail.

Comment: We don't know your "Quaternion" implementation, but line 
quat * vect * quat.Conjugate();
must rotate vector and its length must be same (1.0). Try to find Quaternion.toRotationMatrix() or similar member to be sure that rotation is ok.  If it still not working, be sure that length of quaternion is still 1.0

Comment: The length of my Quaternion is 1.0 when I attempt to rotate it. I edited my ToRotateMatrix method. It works fine when I use it to get my view matrix. @minorlogic

Comment: So use ToRotateMatrix method to rotate DIR vector Vector3<float>( 0, 0, 1 ) or verify your math quat * vect * quat.Conjugate();  to produce vector of unit length